# how to select one date before expiration date

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I'm trying to came up with a query which will allow me to select data with at list one day before the expiration date

I Tried this one. But also doesn't work:

```
SELECT code, prod_name, price, expdate, ROUND((expdate - sysdate), 5) 
from items_info 
WHERE (SELECT ROUND((expdate - sysdate), 5) from items_info) > 1 ;
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my query or tell me how can I come ope with a different one which will satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Oracle, try this:

```
SELECT code, prod_name, price, expdate, ROUND((expdate - sysdate), 5) 
from items_info 
WHERE expdate >= trunc(SYSDATE + 1);
```

The problem with your query (as originally written) was the use of a MySQL function.

The problem with your query as currently written is that the subquery will return more than one row, in most cases, and you'll get an error.  Then, even if the subquery works, you'll get either all rows (because the `where` clause is true) or no rows (because the subquery is false).

Comment: it gives me no data found. What I need to select all the products with at list one day before the expiration date

Comment: Presumably, no such rows exist then.  You can edit your question and provide sample data and expected results.